# CTest and multi-test binaries

Tags: boost-test, ctest

I have a Boost.Test based testsuite, where usually a number of tests is combined into one binary.

If I run them separately from CTest, I get an XML file with one entry per binary, which is not detailed enough in the CI output. There is a [nice script](https://gist.github.com/K-ballo/dd73f748875f63cd854a473319f94a5e) that has CTest interrogate the test binaries and run the tests separately, which gives good results but also increases test time heavily.

Is there a "mixed mode" approach where I can tell CTest to run multiple tests that exist in the same binary together, and only run subsets when the combined test reports a failure?

For example, the [output generated from CTest](https://jenkins.simonrichter.eu/job/linux-kicad-head/ws/build/Testing/) has nine entries, one for each binary registered with `add_test()`. Each binary runs several tests, and the only way to get CTest to report them separately is to instruct it to invoke the binary once for each subtest, which consumes a lot of time.

Comment: Would be good if you could clarify "I get an XML file with one entry per binary, which is not detailed enough in the CI output"

Comment: @Raffi, I have nine binaries performing 300 tests. The CTest report has nine entries, unless I instruct CTest to run each binary once for each contained test, which takes ages.

Comment: Since you are using Boost.Test, you could bypass ctest completely and use Boost.Test to generate a JUnit XML report, which can be picked up by Jenkins. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/log_formats.html

Comment: @sakra, not entirely -- this fails if one of the tests crashes, and there are other tests that are not Boost.Test based (mostly language integration tests where our code is called from a script).

Comment: @simon richter: thanks. How about asking Boost.Test to generate the XML output instead of CTest? Boost.Test will produce a machine parseable XML fr each test case. The ctest output is there to track the result of each `add_test` command.

Comment: @SimonRichter: `this fails if one of the tests crashes`: well this is the responsibility of Boost.Test and if there is a bug, I would be happy to fix it :) OTOH we cannot handle everything in Boost.Test, this is why `ctest` is valuable. Boost.Test will report unit cases, `ctest` will report `add_test` commands. However keep in mind that a crash is sometimes the consequence of running a specific path that puts the program in a particular state: isolating the execution of each test may prevent you from detecting the root cause of the crash.